# Multiple Pouchdb doesn't sync with couchdb

Tags: pouchdb

I am using pouchdb in my electron app,I have more than 15 database in my app. my problem is when i sync  one or two database to couchdb  it works great,but more than 3 couchdb  doesn't  sync.

My code :

```
var sync = PouchDB.sync('mydb', 'http://localhost:5984/mydb', {
  live: true,
  retry: true
})
```

I am also tried  without live but it increase program  complexity,however  I manually want to place the code while perform insert,delete, update  operations.

Can pouchdb watch put,update,delete  events?
To perform manual sync instead live

How should  I achieve?

How to properly sync multiple database?

Which one I choose live sync or manual sync?

Is pouchdb fit for multiple database sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use  database with live sync instead use manual sync with callback

problems:

1. multiple pouchdb sync makes multiple http request eg:(20 pouchdb sync makes 20 http request) so it is bad idea
2. pouchdb live sync is good and fit for one or two database if you make 10 or 20 live pouchdb sync it makes always active10 or 20 http request so it is bad idea and also blocks your frontend dom
3. don't use manualsync with setinterval ,setinterval also bad idea however it calls sync before sync completion

solutions

1. we keep single http request
2. we call each db after one by one completion
3. we always live without dom block however setimeout give relax for your dom

code

```
    function sync(){
      setTimeout(function() {
    var sync = PouchDB.sync('db1', 'http://localhost:5984/db1')
        .on('complete', (info) => {
        PouchDB.sync('db2', 'http://localhost:5984/db2')
        .on('complete', (info) => {
        sync()
    });
    });
   },1000)
}
```